# Is it possible to get the current axis extents of a DataRange1d object (Bokeh)?

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it possible to get the current axis extents of a DataRange1d objects by using a callback?

I've seen quesitons about updating the start and end using a callback, but not for getting the automatically selected extents.

Many thanks.

I wish I could add more informaiton but I don't think there is anything more useful to add.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the start and end of an `DataRange1d` object setting the value.

The example below links the x-axis to two sliders. Moving the a slider has an effect on the visible range.

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

slider_start = Slider(title="x axis start", start=0, end=10, value=0, step=1)
slider_end = Slider(title="x axis start", start=10, end=20, value=11, step=1)

xs = list(range(1,11))
p = figure(width=300, height=300)
p.line(xs, xs)

slider_start.js_link('value', p.x_range, "start")
slider_end.js_link('value', p.x_range, "end")

show(column(slider_start, slider_end, p))
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is about accessing the start and end properties of a DataRange1d object instance within a callback.  Yes, you can do that.  In the following example the Bokeh figure automatically creates a DataRange1d instance for the y-axis range of the plot in order to autofit the given data.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import show

output_notebook() 

my_data = {'x': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
           'y': [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]} 
my_cds = ColumnDataSource(data=my_data) 

p = figure(title='range callback test', output_backend='svg')

p.line(x='x',
       y='y',
       source=my_cds)

cb = CustomJS(args=dict(plot=p),
              code="""
                  let start = plot.y_range.start;
                  let end = plot.y_range.end;
                  plot.title.text = 'y-axis range ' + start.toString() + ' to ' + end.toString();""")
p.y_range.js_on_change('start', cb) 
p.y_range.js_on_change('end', cb)
              
show(p)
```

The Javascript callback changes the title of the plot to show the new y-axis start and end values after using the pan or box zoom tools. Load this example into a notebook to give it a try.